# Use the Midpoint Rule with n=6 to approximate the value of $\int_{a=0}^{ b=1} e^{x^2} dx$. error estimate to find smallest n value

Tags: calculus

The question is Use the Midpoint Rule with n=6 to approximate the value of

$\int_{a=0}^{ b=1} e^{x^2} dx$

I understand i need to find delta x, which is 1/6. When it comes to finding the values to plug in for $f(x)$ i got $M=1/6[f(1/12)+f(1/4)+f(5/12)+f(7/12)+f(3/4)+f(11/12)]$ which after plugging in these answers i got 1.456409832 as the answer. Now, i have a part b) of the question which is, Use the error estimate to find the smallest value of n that can be chosen in order to guarantee that the midpoint rule approximates the integral in part (a) to within 10^-5. I don't even know what part b is suggesting i should do? do i need to use the trapezoidal rule to find out the error estimate? and if i do how does that tell me the smallest value of n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Midpoint Rule, we suppose that $|f''(x)| \le k$, for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$, where $a \le x \le b$. Then, the error estimate is given by:

$$|E_M| \le k\dfrac{(b-a)^3}{24 n^2} \tag 1$$

We have:

$$f(x) = e^{x^2} \rightarrow f'(x) = 2 x e^{x^2} \rightarrow f''(x) = 2 e^{x^2} + 4 x^2 e^{x^2}$$

Where does the max of that occur on the interval? Use your favorite method to find that, but clearly it is an increasing function over the interval, so the max occurs when $x = 1$, so we take:

$$|f''(x)| \le k = 6e$$

Substituting this into $(1)$, yields:

$$|E_M| \le k\dfrac{(b-a)^3}{24 n^2} = 6e \dfrac{1^3}{24 n^2}$$

The problem wants an error $|E_M| \le 10^{-5}$, thus

$$|E_M| = 6e \dfrac{1^3}{24 n^2} \le 10^{-5}$$

Solving for $n$ yields $n \ge 260.686$, so take:

$$n = 261$$

The actual integral is

$$\displaystyle \int_0^1 e^{x^2}~dx = \dfrac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } \text{erfi}(1) = 1.46265$$

Note that this is just a range, so it is entirely possible that the number of iterations is less. Experimentation shows that $184$ were sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

We use midpoint rule while approximating the value of definite integrals.

**Midpoint rule to find approximate integration:**

$\boxed {\displaystyle \int_A^b f(x) dx\approx M_n = \Delta x \left[ f(\overline{x}_1)+f(\overline{x}_2)+.....+f(\overline{x}_n)\right]}$

Here, the interval $[a, b]$ is divided into $n$ equal parts of size $\Delta x$ and height $f(\overline{x})$ is taken at the midpoint of each interval.

So, $\boxed{ \Delta x = \dfrac {b-a}{n}}$

and Midpoint of $ [x_{i-1},\;x_i]=\overline{x}_i=\dfrac {x_{i-1}+x_i}{2}$

**Size of each interval:**

The given interval is $[0, 1]$ and $n=6$, so the interval will be divided into $6$ equal parts.

So, $\Delta x = \dfrac {b-a}{n}=\dfrac {1-0}{6}=\dfrac {1}{6}$

That means the size of each interval is $\dfrac {1}{6}$

**Graphical Representation:**
[image]

Here, $x_0=0,\\ 
x_1=\dfrac {1}{6}\\ 
x_2=\dfrac {2}{6}=\dfrac {1}{3}\\
x_3=\dfrac {3}{6}=\dfrac {1}{2}\\
x_4=\dfrac {4}{6}=\dfrac {2}{3}\\
x_5=\dfrac {5}{6}\\
x_6=\dfrac {6}{6}=1\\
$

Midpoint approximation of $\displaystyle\int_0^1 e^{x^2}dx$

Comparison of the given integral with equation (i) :

$\displaystyle\int_a^b f{(x)}\;dx$ and $\displaystyle\int_0^1 e^{x^2}\;dx$

Here, $f(x) = e^{x^2}, \;a=0$ and $b = 1$

**Finding the midpoint $(\overline{x}_i)$ of each interval:**

$\because \overline{x}_i = \dfrac {x_{i-1}+x_i}{2}$

$\therefore \overline{x}_1 = \dfrac {x_{0}+x_1}{2} = \dfrac {1}{2} \left[ 0+\dfrac {1}{6}\right]=\dfrac {1}{12}$

$\therefore \overline{x}_2 = \dfrac {x_{1}+x_2}{2} = \dfrac {1}{2} \left[ \dfrac {1}{6}+\dfrac {1}{3}\right]=\dfrac {1}{4}$

$\therefore \overline{x}_3 = \dfrac {x_{2}+x_3}{2} = \dfrac {1}{2} \left[ \dfrac {1}{3}+\dfrac {1}{2}\right]=\dfrac {5}{12}$

$\therefore \overline{x}_4 = \dfrac {x_{3}+x_4}{2} = \dfrac {1}{2} \left[ \dfrac {1}{2}+\dfrac {2}{3}\right]=\dfrac {7}{12}$

$\therefore \overline{x}_5 = \dfrac {x_{4}+x_5}{2} = \dfrac {1}{2} \left[ \dfrac {2}{3}+\dfrac {5}{6}\right]=\dfrac {3}{4}$

$\therefore \overline{x}_6 = \dfrac {x_{5}+x_6}{2} = \dfrac {1}{2} \left[ \dfrac {5}{6}+1\right]=\dfrac {11}{12}$

Now put all the values in equation (i)

$\boxed {\displaystyle \int_A^b f(x) dx\approx M_n = \Delta x \left[ f(\overline{x}_1)+f(\overline{x}_2)+.....+f(\overline{x}_n)\right]}$

$\because \;n=6$

$\therefore M_n=M_6$ and $\overline{x}_n=\overline{x}_6$

$\Rightarrow \displaystyle \int_0^1 e^{x^2}\;dx \approx M_6=\dfrac{1}{6} \left[ f(\overline{x}_1)+f(\overline{x}_2)+f(\overline{x}_3+f(\overline{x}_4))+f(\overline{x}_5)+f(\overline{x}_6)\right]$

$M_6=\dfrac {1}{6}\left[f\left(\dfrac{1}{12}\right)+f\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)+f\left(\dfrac{5}{12}\right)+f\left(\dfrac{7}{12}\right)+f\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)+f\left(\dfrac{11}{12}\right)\right]$

$=\dfrac {1}{6} \left[e^{(1/12)^2}+e^{(1/4)^2}+e^{(5/12)^2}+e^{(7/12)^2}+e^{(3/4)^2}+e^{(11/12)^2}\right]$

$M_6 \approx 1.4564$

**Error bound for Midpoint Rule:**
If $f''(x) \leq k$ for some $ k\epsilon R$ then error bound for midpoint rule is

$|E_M| \leq k \dfrac {(b-a)^3}{24n^2}$ ... (ii)

where $a \leq x \leq b$

Here, $k$ is the maximum value of second derivative that we can get because it gives an error bound which will be as close to the actual error as possible.

Since we have $f(x) = e^{x^2},\;a=0,\;b=1$ and $n = 6$

$\therefore f'(x) = 2x\; e^{x^2}$

and $f''(x) = \dfrac {d}{dx} \left ( 2x\,e^{x^2} \right) =2 [x \cdot e^{x^2} \cdot 2x+e^{x^2} \cdot 1]$

$f''(x) = 2e^{x^2} [2x^2+1]$

$\therefore$ The maximum value of f\,''(x) for the interval $[a, b] = [0, 1]$ is $6e$

So, $\boxed {k = 6e}$

according to question, the error estimate
$|E_M|\leq10^{-5}$

$|E_M| = \dfrac{6e(1-0)^3}{24×n^2}\leq10^{-5}$

$=\dfrac{e}{4×n^2}\leq10^{-5}$

$=\dfrac{e}{4×10^{-5}}\leq n^2$

$=\dfrac{e×10^5}{4}\leq n^2$

$260.685\leq n$

$n \approx 261$

It is the smallest value of $ n. $